# How to return all column in two table with different values

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to return two column from different tables with different values.

This is my table.

[image]

Here's my code :

```
SELECT products_name, qty_in, qty_out FROM `products` 
LEFT JOIN products_in ON products.id = products_in.product_id 
LEFT JOIN products_out ON products.id = products_out.product_id
ORDER BY products.id ASC
```

And the result :

[image]

It should be return like this.

[image]

Help me. How to return all columns with NULL values is still there.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
with q1 as (
Select * from products 
Left join products_in ON products.id =                  products_in.product_id), 
q2 as ( select * from products
LEFT JOIN products_out ON products.id =                                    products_out.product_id
)Select * from products p
Left join q1.product_id = p.id
Left join q2.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: where should i put the "with"?

Comment: hi, i've just tried it and it returns the same result as i attached above :( can you help me with another code?